# Content Type exists in Database but does not show up

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type, but I can not find it in the create content list. When I checked mysql database, the content type exists there. What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you logged in with the same account as the one used for creating the content type? What happens if you create yet another content type (just for testing purposes)?

Comment: install devel module and try re-build menu